Display selected item at top in the dropdown list of RibbonComboBox
I have a WPF-RibbonComboBox binded to the list with >100 entries.
When an item in the middle of the list is selected, at reopening the combobox the selected item is displayed at the bottom of the dropdown list.
How can I scroll the list before dropping, so that the selected item is then displayed on top?
Reordering the list like here: suggestion for asp is not possible.
Any ideas appreciated!
UPD: Sorry, my fault - I'm using a RibbonComboBox in this case.

How do you fill ComboBox.ItemsSource with the collection of items? What have you tried to change the order of the collection?

If you set the MaxDropDownHeight on the ComboBox, and there are "enough items", it behaves as desired (in my experience).

@emoacht I fill it by binding to an ObservableCollection of objects. The order of items is very important it cannot be changed. I only came across of that possibility and wanted to ommit such proposals outright

@Gerry Schmitz
I'm using a RibbonComboBox in this case (question updated). It doesn't have MaxDropDownHeight, but it has DropDownHeight. Unfortunately setting this property didn't bring the desired behaviour.

If we're talking "ribbons", those are (typically) "small" lists; e.g. "font properties". A 100 item list is a "main event".
